# MacOS Outlook 2019 how to make PDF body of email in 2020

Tags: macos, ms-office, pdf

I googled a lot but couldn't find an answer. I want to send an email using outlook (latest) on Mac OS and I want to make the body of the email be a PDF. (not as an attachment).

Comment: Have you tried googling “How to embed PDF outlook?” I yielded [this YouTube tutorial for you](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=apsvH2AIE3E) which basically says to insert the PDF as an object in the body or the email. There is also [a Microsoft support document](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-an-object-in-Word-or-Outlook-8fc1ea53-0e01-4603-a4cf-98c49b6ea3f5) that says to do the same thing.

Comment: @bret7600 - both of those use OLE or [Object Linking and Embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Linking_and_Embedding) which is a Windows technology and not available to macOS.

Comment: I don't recommend doing this because this is a surefire way to get tagged as spam - sending emails with no body and embedded files.  Do a mass mailing like this and there's a good chance you get put on a spam black list.  My suggestion is to use a [responsive HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp) template instead